# fiware-perseo CEP is not sending emails I can't see the rules in mongo but when i run get rules yes

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cep

When I set a rule to send an email with fiware-perseo cep when an attribute change, I don't get the email and if I look for the rule in Mongo, I can't see it, but if I execute get rules from API get, I see the rule. I use docker and I don't know if I have set up the .yml file correctly to set up perseo-core, perseo-fe, and orion, I have followed the guide:

https://perseo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/

I don't know if in Orion I have to set up anything to point at Perseo.
I provide the code in the code section.

A part from the .yml code, I have created this Rule through the API:

```
    {
    "name": "prueba1",
    "text": "select *, \"prueba1\" as ruleName ,ev.temperature? as temperature, ev.id? as id from pattern [every ev=iotEvent(cast(cast(temperature?,String),float)>45.5 and type=\"AirQualityObserved\")]",
    "action": {
        "type": "email",
        "template": "Entity ${id} temperature is ${temperature}",
        "parameters": {
            "to": "antonio.moreno@someplace.com",
            "from": "avisos@someplace.com",
            "subject": "High Temp"
        }
    }
}

version: "3.1"
services:
  mongo-db:
    image: mongo:3.2
    hostname: mongo-db
    container_name: fiware-mongo-db
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
    expose:
        - "27017"    
    networks:
        - smartcity

    volumes:
      - "mongo-db:/data"
  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    hostname: mysql-db
    container_name: fiware-mysql-db
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - smartcity
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%"
    volumes:
      - mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql"
  orion:

    image: fiware/orion:latest
    hostname: orion
    container_name: fiware-orion-mongo
    networks:
        - smartcity
    expose:
        - "1026"
    ports:
        - "1026:1026"
    command: -dbhost mongo-db -logLevel DEBUG
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:1026/version || exit 1

  cygnus:
    image: fiware/cygnus-ngsi:1.10.0
    hostname: cygnus
    container_name: fiware-cygnus
    depends_on:
        - mysql-db
        - mongo-db
    networks:
        - smartcity
    expose:
      - "5080"

    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
      - "5051:5051"
      - "5054:5054"
      - "5080:5080"

    environment:
        - "CYGNUS_MULTIAGENT=true" # Whether to persist data into multiple databases.
        - "CYGNUS_MONGO_HOSTS=mongo-db:27017" # Comma separated list of Mongo-DB servers which Cygnus will contact to persist historical context data
        - "CYGNUS_MONGO_DATA_MODEL=dm-by-service-path" # data_model
        - "CYGNUS_MONGO_ATTR_PERSISTENCE=column" # data_model
        - "CYGNUS_MONGO_DB_PREFIX=sti-"
        - "CYGNUS_MONGO_USER=root"
        - "CYGNUS_MONGO_PASS=example"
        - "CYGNUS_STH_DB_PREFIX=sth-"
        - "CYGNUS_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG" # The logging level for Cygnus
        - "CYGNUS_SERVICE_PORT=5050" # Notification Port that Cygnus listens when subcribing to context data changes
        - "CYGNUS_API_PORT=5080" # Port that Cygnus listens on for operational reasons
        - "CYGNUS_MYSQL_HOST=mysql-db" # Hostname of the MySQL server used to persist historical context data 
        - "CYGNUS_MYSQL_PORT=3306" # Port that the MySQL server uses to listen to commands
        - "CYGNUS_MYSQL_USER=root" # Username for the MySQL database user
        - "CYGNUS_MYSQL_PASS=1234" # Password for the MySQL database user
        - "CYGNUS_MYSQL_DATA_MODEL=dm-by-service-path" # data_model
        - "CYGNUS_MYSQL_ATTR_PERSISTENCE=row"

    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:5080/v1/version || exit 1

  iot-agent:
    image: fiware/iotagent-ul:1.8.0
    hostname: iot-agent
    container_name: fiware-iot-agent
    networks:
        - smartcity
    ports:
        - "4041:4041"
        - "7896:7896"
    environment:
        - "IOTA_CB_HOST=orion" # name of the context broker to update context
        - "IOTA_CB_PORT=1026" # port the context broker listens on to update context
        - "IOTA_NORTH_PORT=4041"
        - "IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE=mongodb" #Whether to hold IoT device info in memory or in a database
        - "IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG" #The log level of the IoT Agent
        - "IOTA_TIMESTAMP=true"
        - "IOTA_MONGO_HOST=mongo-db" # The host name of ongoDB
        - "IOTA_MONGO_PORT=27017" # The port mongoDB is listening on
        - "IOTA_MONGO_DB=iot-smartcity" # The name of the database used in mongoDB
        - "IOTA_HTTP_PORT=7896" # The port used for device traffic over HTTP
        - "IOTA_PROVIDER_URL=http://iot-agent:4041"
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:4041/iot/about || exit 1

  sth-comet:
    image: fiware/sth-comet
    hostname: sth-comet
    container_name: fiware-sth-comet
    networks:
        - smartcity
    ports:
        - "8666:8666"
    environment:
        - STH_HOST=0.0.0.0
        - STH_PORT=8666
        - DB_PREFIX=sth-commet-
        - "DB_URI=mongo-db:27017"
        - LOGOPS_LEVEL=DEBUG
  perseo-core:
    image: fiware/perseo-core
    hostname: perseo-core
    container_name: fiware-perseo-core
    depends_on:
        - mongo-db
        - orion
    networks:
        - smartcity
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    environment:

        - PERSEO_FE_URL=http://perseo-fe:9090
        - MAX_AGE=6000

  perseo-front:
    image: fiware/perseo
    hostname: perseo-fe
    container_name: fiware-perseo-fe
    networks:
        - smartcity
    ports:
        - "9090:9090"
    depends_on:
         - perseo-core
    environment:
        - PERSEO_ENDPOINT_HOST=perseo-core
        - PERSEO_ENDPOINT_PORT=8080
        - PERSEO_MONGO_HOST=mongo-db
        - PERSEO_MONGO_URL=http://mongo-db:27017
        - PERSEO_MONGO_ENDPOINT=mongo-db:27017  
        - PERSEO_ORION_URL=http://orion:1026/
        - PERSEO_LOG_LEVEL=debug
        - PERSEO_CORE_URL=http://perseo-core:8080
        - PERSEO_SMTP_SECURE=true
        - PERSEO_MONGO_USER:"root"
        - PERSEO_MONGO_PASSWORD:"example"
        - PERSEO_SMTP_HOST=mail.someplace.com
        - PERSEO_SMTP_PORT=25
        - PERSEO_SMTP_AUTH_USER=someplace@someplace.com
        - PERSEO_SMTP_AUTH_PASS=xxxxx
        - PERSEO_NOTICES_PATH='/notices'
        - PERSEO_RULES_PATH='/rules'

    networks:
        - smartcity        

volumes:
  mongo-db: 
  mysql-db:

networks:
  smartcity:
    driver: bridge
```

I want to be able to send an email when an attribute exceeds a threshold, now it is not working.

Comment: How to use - PERSEO_NOTICES_PATH='/notices'
        - PERSEO_RULES_PATH='/rules'

Comment: How to set - MAX_AGE to infinite time or to 10 years e.g.?

Comment: I set up a subscription from Orion Context broker to Perseo CEP:                                        {
 "subject": {

  "entities": [
 {
     "idPattern": ".*",
     "type": "AirQualityObserved"
 }
  ],
   "condition": {
  "expression": {
   "q": "temperature>45"
  }
 }
 },
 "notification": {
 "http": {
 "url": "http://perseo-fe:9090/notices"
 },
  "attrs": [
   "temperature"
  ]
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

Looking to Perseo configuration it seems you have left the configuration template for SMTP, e.g:

```
- PERSEO_SMTP_HOST=mail.someplace.com
```

Note `mail.someplace.com` is just an example but it is not a real SMTP server. You should adjust this (and maybe other `PERSEO_SMTP_xxx` parameters) configuration parameters to fit the ones in your SMTP server.

**EDIT**: in order to check the rule condition and know if the problem is in the rule condition or in your SMTP configuration, you could try the same rule condition but with a simpler action (for instance, [doing a HTTP action](https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-fe/blob/master/documentation/plain_rules.md#http-request-action), combined with some kind of echo-ing service like [RequestBin](http://requestbin.net/))

**EDIT2:** `msg=missing subservice header, msg=missing service header` typically mean that the incoming request doesn't have the `fiware-service` and  `fiware-servicepath` HTTP headers in which multitenancy is based. The FIWARE multitenancy model is described [here](https://thinking-cities.readthedocs.io/en/master/multitenancy/index.html).

Comment: Not sure if there are more problems with your set up, but I think that at least the one I describe in my above answer should be solved.

Comment: The email server is not that one, is another one correct but I didn't want to show it. I get this error in the logs of perseo: msg=missing subservice header, msg=missing service header

Comment: Here I have the logs:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56091838/perseo-front-end-is-showing-this-errors-in-the-logs-msg-missing-subservice-head

Comment: Please find additional information in EDIT and EDIT2 in my answer

Comment: Only remains to fix is how to set  - MAX_AGE to last for ever

Comment: Could you do the question related with MAX_AGE in an independent question post (or cite the link to it if already exists), please? It is better to use different posts for different questions in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

the correct is: http://perseo-fe-ip:9090/rules, with that it works.

Store the rule in mongodb and fire the rule properly.