# Perseo front end is showing this errors in the logs: msg=missing subservice header msg=missing service header

Tags: fiware, fiware-cep, fiware-perseo

Using perseo cep, I set a rule to it. I get this message in the Perseo fron End's Log: http://perseo-core:8080/perseo-core/rules returns {"code":200,"body":{}}. Then when I modify an attribute, in the Perseo Core's Log I see this message: msg=Firing Rule: MapEventBean. So far, so good, but then again in the Perseo FE's log I get the message: msg=missing subservice header msg=missing service header, and it is not updating my entity.

This is the log:
time=2019-05-11T14:30:48.774Z | lvl=INFO | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=checkRequest | comp=perseo-fe | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=missing subservice header
time=2019-05-11T14:30:48.774Z | lvl=INFO | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=checkRequest | comp=perseo-fe | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=missing service header
time=2019-05-11T14:30:48.774Z | lvl=INFO | corr=5229c32c-362a-43f6-acda-11d6d8198261; perseocep=21 | trans=5229c32c-362a-43f6-acda-11d6d8198261 | op=/version | path=/version | comp=perseo-fe | srv=unknownt | subsrv=/ | from=::1 | msg=incoming request {"method":"GET","url":"/version","headers":{"host":"localhost:9090","user-agent":"curl/7.52.1","accept":"*/*"},"body":{},"subservice":"/","service":"unknownt"}
time=2019-05-11T14:30:48.774Z | lvl=INFO | corr=5229c32c-362a-43f6-acda-11d6d8198261; perseocep=21 | trans=5229c32c-362a-43f6-acda-11d6d8198261 | op=/version | path=/version | comp=perseo-fe | srv=unknownt | subsrv=/ | from=::1 | msg=sending

Mi Rule:

{
    "name": "pruebaUpdate",
    "text": "select ev.temperature? as temperature, ev.id? as id, \"pruebaUpdate\" as ruleName from pattern [every ev=iotEvent(cast(cast(temperature?,String),float) > 45 and type=\"AirQualityObserved\")]",
    "action": [{
        "type": "update",
        "parameters": {
            "id":"${id}",
            "type":"AirQualityObserved",
            "version": "2",
            "attributes":[
                {
                    "name": "abnormal",
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "value": "true"
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
}

I want to update one attribute when other attribute is higher than a value, that attribute is in some entities but not in other of the same type. I am not getting to update that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`msg=missing subservice header, msg=missing service header` typically mean that the incoming request doesn't have the `fiware-service` and  `fiware-servicepath` HTTP headers in which multitenancy is based. The FIWARE multitenancy model is described [here](https://thinking-cities.readthedocs.io/en/master/multitenancy/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Placing the rule in the correct place I didn't get the error of "missing service subservice". I registered the rule with http://perseo-fe-ip:9090/rules and I fixed the problems.